# Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#

I try lot of things to resolve the issue but didn't find the right answer. when click on Save button, following msg appear;

> > Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Data.dll

and highlight the line

> > public static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(s);

Here is the detail code.

> Connection.cs File

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace IMS
{
    class Connection
    {
        private static string s = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\\Connect.txt");
        public static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(s);
    }
}
```

> Where i write the insertion code to insert data in table

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace IMS
{
    class insertion
    {
        public void InsertUser(string name, string username, string password, string email, Int16 status)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sy_InsertUser", Connection.con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
                Connection.con.Open();
                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()>= 1)
                {
                    mainclass.ShowSucsMsg("User Added Successfuly");
                }
                Connection.con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Dashborad.ShowExpMsg(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Data Save Button Code

```
 public override void savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            insertion obj = new insertion();
            obj.InsertUser(usnametxt.Text, usUsernametxt.Text, usPasswordtxt.Text, usEmailtxt.Text, Status);
        }
```

> App.Cofig

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="" value="\\Connect.txt" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the connection string itself. The error complains about the connection string. All the other code isn't really relevant

Comment: What is the value of s on that line where you get that exception?

Comment: BTW using a static connection is a **VERY** bad idea. Connections are meant to be short-lived, created right before they're used and disposed immediately afterwards. Global connections accumulate locks and lead to severe concurrency issues even with a dozen users. Locks acquired outside a transaction are held until the connection closes. This means that an UPDATE operation using `con` will result in Exclusive locks held until the application terminates. It's *very* easy to run into deadlocks this way, simply by having another instance open, on another machinee

Comment: And if the InsertUser method throws an exception after you have opened the connection you have forgotten to close. This leads to another error when you try to reopen the connection again. Search about how to use the _using statement_

Comment: @Russ Here is the Connection String in App.Config `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="IMS" 

    connectionString="Data Source=NAINASEMI-PC\SA; Initial Catalog=IMS; User ID=sa; Password=63377; Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: @AmnaMudassar: doesn't answer my question.  What is the value of s when you encounter that exception?

Comment: s is only a string to read all text when connection established.

Comment: @AmnaMudassar: That STILL doesn't answer the question.  I can see it's used for your connection string. I'm asking what the value of s is when you use it to open the question.  Use your debugger, and when you get the exception, examine the value of s.  I bet you will see that the connection string is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't keep your connection as a static. You should use connection this way:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
                var command = new SqlCommand("sy_InsertUser", connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
                command.connection.Open();
                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery()>= 1)
                {
                    mainclass.ShowSucsMsg("User Added Successfuly");
                }
       
    }
```

Comment: almost worked, Now on clicking Save Button new message appear "a connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error during login process(provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)"

Comment: Could you please show the connection string that you use?

Comment: `<connectionStrings>     <add name="IMS"       connectionString="Data Source=NAINASEMI-PC\SA; Initial Catalog=IMS; User ID=sa; Password=63377; Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>   </connectionStrings>`

Comment: @AmnaMudassar Try to use Integrated Security=False;

Comment: And if it  still doesn' t work try to add to the end of string "Connect Timeout=15; Encrypt=False; Packet Size=4096

Comment: Everything is going perfect in application till i click on SAVE button to save data in Database, as soon as i click, it show an error,

Cannot open database "IMS" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'sa'.

Comment: "Everything is going perfect" - what do you mean. You can get data from DB but can't save? Did you change to false Integrated Security?

Comment: oh sorry, my mistake, problem solved, my DB name was manually pasted, that was wrong, it was no IMS. Thanks,